# Change back-ground color of stacked nav pills in twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap 3.

I want to change background color of stacked nav pill (ul)

**css**

```
   .red .active a,
.red .active a:hover {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked red" id="NavParent">
                    <li class=""><a href="#" onclick="MenuToggle(this)"><span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down">
                    </span>Home</a>
                        <div class="collapse">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <li class=""><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you missed to add the class `.red`

```
.red, .red .active a,
.red .active a:hover {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```